# How to make a menu until user inputs to exit

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I want to loop a input (repeating) until enter 5 to exit. For example i input 1 display case 1, then ask input again , enter 4 and display case 4. Until i enter 5 to exit.

The below code just keep asking me input and never show me output.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("1.Soup\n2.Main Course\n3.Dessert\n4.Beverage\n5.Exit");
        //ask input from user
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        int input=scan.nextInt();
        int check=input;
        //keep looping until user input 5 which is Exit
        while (input!=5){
             System.out.println("Please enter 1-5\n1.Soup\n2.Main Course\n3.Dessert\n4.Beverage\n5.Exit");
             int input1=scan.nextInt();
             check=input1;
        }
        switch (check){
            case 1 :
                System.out.println("1.Mushroom Soup\n2.Miso Soup\n3.Tomato Soup");
                break;
            case 2 :
                System.out.println("1.Chiken Katsu Don\n2.Curry Katsu Don\n3.Teriyaki Katsu Don\n4.Curry Udon");
                break;
            case 3 :
                System.out.println("1.Matcha Ice Cream\n2.Chocolate Ice Cream\n3.Oreo Chocolate\n4.Dango");
                break;
            case 4 :
                System.out.println( "1.Green Tea\n2.Matcha RedBean\n3.Chocolate MilkShake\n4.Strawberry Ice Blended");
                break;
            case 5 :
                System.exit(0);
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` should be inside the `while`. You must ask another input only after the first has been processed.

```
while (input is valid)
    get input
    process input
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `switch` statement is outside the `while-loop` scope.

```
        while (input!=5)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1-5\n1.Soup\n2.Main Course\n3.Dessert\n4.Beverage\n5.Exit");
            int input1=scan.nextInt();
            check=input1;
            switch (check)
            {
            case 1 :
                System.out.println("1.Mushroom Soup\n2.Miso Soup\n3.Tomato Soup");
                break;
            case 2 :
                System.out.println("1.Chiken Katsu Don\n2.Curry Katsu Don\n3.Teriyaki Katsu Don\n4.Curry Udon");
                break;
            case 3 :
                System.out.println("1.Matcha Ice Cream\n2.Chocolate Ice Cream\n3.Oreo Chocolate\n4.Dango");
                break;
            case 4 :
                System.out.println( "1.Green Tea\n2.Matcha RedBean\n3.Chocolate MilkShake\n4.Strawberry Ice Blended");
                break;
            case 5 :
                System.exit(0);
               break;
            }        
       }
```

EDIT: Also, as others have pointed out in more recent answers, your loop condition variable isn't being reset inside the loop (but that's incidental to the question you asked and is, arguably, a different problem).

Comment: Interesting. Never noticed before that editing an answer blows any pre-edit comments away. Fascinating.

Comment: I don't think it does. Maybe a mod had a cleanup.

Comment: How odd. I didn't notice anything contentious.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix it like this:

```
do{
    System.out.println("Please enter 1-5\n1.Soup\n2.Main Course\n3.Dessert\n4.Beverage\n5.Exit");
    int input1=scan.nextInt();
    check=input1;
    switch (check){
    case 1 :
        System.out.println("1.Mushroom Soup\n2.Miso Soup\n3.Tomato Soup");
        break;
    case 2 :
        System.out.println("1.Chiken Katsu Don\n2.Curry Katsu Don\n3.Teriyaki Katsu Don\n4.Curry Udon");
        break;
    case 3 :
        System.out.println("1.Matcha Ice Cream\n2.Chocolate Ice Cream\n3.Oreo Chocolate\n4.Dango");
        break;
    case 4 :
        System.out.println( "1.Green Tea\n2.Matcha RedBean\n3.Chocolate MilkShake\n4.Strawberry Ice Blended");
        break;
    case 5 :
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
}
while (input!=5);
```

Adding a Do-While loop you guarantee it will show it at least once.

Or you can simply

```
while (input!=5){
    System.out.println("Please enter 1-5\n1.Soup\n2.Main Course\n3.Dessert\n4.Beverage\n5.Exit");
    int input1=scan.nextInt();
    check=input1;
    switch (check){
    case 1 :
        System.out.println("1.Mushroom Soup\n2.Miso Soup\n3.Tomato Soup");
        break;
    case 2 :
        System.out.println("1.Chiken Katsu Don\n2.Curry Katsu Don\n3.Teriyaki Katsu Don\n4.Curry Udon");
        break;
    case 3 :
        System.out.println("1.Matcha Ice Cream\n2.Chocolate Ice Cream\n3.Oreo Chocolate\n4.Dango");
        break;
    case 4 :
        System.out.println( "1.Green Tea\n2.Matcha RedBean\n3.Chocolate MilkShake\n4.Strawberry Ice Blended");
        break;
    case 5 :
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two fixes. Firstly, move your `switch` block inside your `while` loop. Secondly, your while loop will never terminate because you only assign `input` once.

I can only imagine some of this confusion comes from having too many variables in your code: `input`, `input1`, `check`...

It seems to me your code can be greatly simplified. Consider the following alternative - we can use a simple `while(true)` loop, since you plan to exit the VM when `5` is entered:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Please enter 1-5\n1.Soup\n2.Main Course\n3.Dessert\n4.Beverage\n5.Exit");

        int input = scan.nextInt();

        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("1.Mushroom Soup\n2.Miso Soup\n3.Tomato Soup");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("1.Chiken Katsu Don\n2.Curry Katsu Don\n3.Teriyaki Katsu Don\n4.Curry Udon");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("1.Matcha Ice Cream\n2.Chocolate Ice Cream\n3.Oreo Chocolate\n4.Dango");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("1.Green Tea\n2.Matcha RedBean\n3.Chocolate MilkShake\n4.Strawberry Ice Blended");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```